# Corda Tokens SKD: Getting Token Balance

Tags: corda

I'm playing around with Corda Tokens SDK and trying to figure out how to get the balance of an issued token.

In terminal of **PartyA**:

1. I created a new token: `start CreateExampleEvolvableToken data: NEW_TOKEN`
2. I issued that token to PartyB: `start ExampleFlowWithEvolvableToken evolvableTokenId: 96e57632-2070-4720-ba37-dea61e7c7557, amount: 100, recipient: PartyB`

In terminal of **PartyB**:

If I run `run vaultQuery contractStateType: com.template.states.ExampleEvolvableTokenType`, I get the token type state; not the balance.

So my question is, what command gives me the information: **PartyB has 100 of NEW_TOKEN**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All tokens in Corda are issued as `FungibleToken` or `NonFungileToken`, these are modeled as states in Corda. So you could do a simple vaultQuery to fetch the states, use a filter if you want a specific token. There is no amount property for `NonFungibleToken` since it is unique and only one issued type can exist. `FungibleToken` has an `amount` property which would represent the amount of the token held by a party.

Learn more amount Corda Token SDK here:

https://medium.com/corda/introduction-to-token-sdk-in-corda-9b4dbcf71025